# SpringBootTest + H2 Memory Database = ERROR o.h.t.s.i.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl

Tags: hibernate, h2, spring-boot-test

I'm getting error messages after my tests completed using H2 memory database:

```
10:23:43.566 [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
10:23:43.573 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:23:43.580 [main] ERROR o.h.t.s.i.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl - HHH000478: Unsuccessful: 
    drop table cup_orchestrator.cup_orchestrator.country if exists
10:23:43.581 [main] ERROR o.h.t.s.i.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl - HHH000478: Unsuccessful: 
    drop table cup_orchestrator.cup_orchestrator.cpo_cycle_type if exists
```

It seems hibernate tries to drop a table and cannot, but the table was created because my 
tests used this tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by upgrading spring boot version.

Seems that it had been fixed in `v2.5.0`.

I couldn't find something about it in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.0), but I checked it by testing manually `2.4.13` (contains the errors) vs `2.5.0` errors disappeared).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).